# Object doesn't support this property or method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, activex, hta

Okay, so I think I'm derping here again.. I'm using this code in a HTA (for a intranet application) instead of using just a normal HTML page.. when I "submit" my code I get the error message "Object doesn't support this property or method on line: 24 (which is where I close my file (via activexobjects)

HTML page uses:

```
<input name="Button1" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getFormContent()" />
```

My Javascript file (external .js page) :

```
// Global Variables First!
var AllFormContent
var ManagerValue
function managerValueTrue(ManagerValue) {
ManagerValue = "Yes"
}
function managerValueFalse(ManagerValue) {
ManagerValue = "No"
}

function getFormContent(ManagerValue) {
var Mudkips = document.getElementById('ManagerName');
var ManagerName = Mudkips.options[Mudkips.selectedIndex].text;
var RandomText = document.getElementById('RandomText').value;
var Comment = document.getElementById('Comments').value;
AllFormContent = ManagerName + ", " + ManagerValue + ", " + RandomText + ", " + Comments
writeMyFile();
}

 function writeMyFile(AllFormContent) {
var filesys = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("C:\\MyFile.csv", 8) ;
filetxt.WriteLine(AllFormContent);
filetxt.Close;
}
```

"line 24" refers to "filetext.close" though I imagine it might have to do with "AllFormContent" or a previous line? I've tested the code, I know I get to the writeMyFile function, I know the ActiveXObject works fine.. Any ideas on what I'm derping with here?
Thanks :]

Comment: Do you not just need to add the brackets? i.e. filetxt.Close() - Sorry not used this before, so just a guess

Comment: I don't believe so, I have had too/seen this before the .Close is just closing the stream to the csv :\

Comment: Just fix it to use `Close` method: `filetext.Close()`.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone suggested in the comments but didn't answer, just add parantheses to Close at writeMyFile().

```
function writeMyFile(AllFormContent) {
    var filesys = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("C:\\MyFile.csv", 8) ;
    filetxt.WriteLine(AllFormContent);
    filetxt.Close();
}
```

`Close` is a method of the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` in JavaScript while it's more like a subprocedure for VBScript. To call functions and methods in JavaScript, you have to close the reference with parantheses while in VBScript it is unnecessary to call a `Sub` with parantheses and with multiple `params` it even gives an error (I think?).

There is not alot of documentation for JScript and the ActiveXObjects for WScript, most of it is covered in VBScript so there is often confusion in this aspect.